# Referencing a blog post in text?

Tags: citations, blog

I'm writing a book, and in the appendix I explain many of my inspirations. I reference many books like so:

> This part was inspired by John Smith's famous book *Famous Book*.

However, I realized I also wanted to mention how a specific blog post inspired me, too. Right now I've written:

> I was also inspired by Jane Smith's article "Blog Article" on her blog, Jane's Blog.

Is this the correct way to reference a blog post? I'm not looking to give in-text citations or create a works cited page at the end of a paper, just mention that it inspired some specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to citations, there is no universally correct method. There are various style guides that specify different ways of doing citations. Publications often specify that the articles or books that they publish must use a certain citation format. Certain academic disciplines may adopt a particular citation standard for works in that field. But these apply only if you are writing in that field or writing for a particular publication that requires a particular format. If not, you can do citation any way you like. You can pick from one of the many citation formats available or you can make up one to suit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is you are ***acknowledging*** who inspired you. There is no fixed format for this, and what you have written is perfectly fine.

---

You may want to consider [not writing acknowledgments](https://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/against-acknowledgments), though ;-)